# Writing an XML in Matlab: How to add reference to DTD?

Tags: java, xml, matlab, dom

I'm trying to write an XML file using Matlab and I need to specify a DOCTYPE DTD at the header, but I haven't found any method for this in the Matlab documentation or questions related. Every question involving a DTD reference is about how to **read** an XML into Matlab.

What I am able to do now is an XML file of the type

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
    <child>
        Hello world!
    </child>
</root>
```

with the code

```
docNode = com.mathworks.xml.XMLUtils.createDocument('root');
root = docNode.getDocumentElement;

child = docNode.createElement('child');
child.appendChild(docNode.createTextNode('Hello World!'));
root.appendChild(child);

xmlwrite(docNode)
```

However, I need the file to include a DTD reference:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE root SYSTEM "root.dtd" []>
<root>
    <child>
        Hello world!
    </child>
</root>
```

Is there any function in *com.mathworks.xml.XMLUtils* for this? Or will I have to open the generated XML and manually insert the DTD reference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can stay with using the [org.w3c.dom](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/package-summary.html) package: you can use the [createDocumentType](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/DOMImplementation.html#createDocumentType-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) method of [DOMImplementation](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/DOMImplementation.html).

```
domImpl = docNode.getImplementation();
doctype = domImpl.createDocumentType('root', 'SYSTEM', 'root.dtd');
```

With this update the full sample code is:

```
docNode = com.mathworks.xml.XMLUtils.createDocument('root');
domImpl = docNode.getImplementation();
doctype = domImpl.createDocumentType('root', 'SYSTEM', 'root.dtd');
docNode.appendChild(doctype);

root = docNode.getDocumentElement;

child = docNode.createElement('child');
child.appendChild(docNode.createTextNode('Hello World!'));
root.appendChild(child);

xmlwrite(docNode)
```

*Output*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE root PUBLIC "SYSTEM" "root.dtd">
<root>
   <child>Hello World!</child>
</root>
```